# how to get the corresponding key for the maximum value in dictionary list in the most effecient way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Let's assume that there is a dictionary list like this one:

```
lst = {(1,1):2, (1,2):5, (1,3):10, (1,4):14, (1,6):22}
```

I want a simple (the most efficient) function that returns the dictionary key which its value is the maximum.

For example:

```
key_for_max_value_in_dict(lst) = (1,6)
```

because the tuple `(1,6)` has the most value (22).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a comprehension for that like:

#### Code:

```
max((v, k) for k, v in lst.items())[1]
```

#### How does it work?

Iterate over the `items()` in the `dict`, and emit them as tuples of `(value, key)` with the `value` first in the tuple.  `max()` can then find the largest `value`, because tuples sort by each element in the tuple, with first element matching first element.  Then take the second element (`[1]`) of the max tuple since it is the `key` value for the max `value` in the `dict`.

#### Test Code:

```
lst = {(1,1):2, (1,2):5, (1,3):10, (1,4):14, (1,6):22}
print(max((v, k) for k, v in lst.items())[1])
```

#### Results;

```
(1, 6)
```

Comment: There is one thing I forgot to mention. Consider the example list. if there were 2(or more) keys with the same value which happens to be maximum, would it be possible to extract all those keys?

Comment: I've updated my example to show how you could do this.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with this code which might be the most efficient one: 
`max(lst, key=lambda x: lst[x])`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a regular unsorted dictionary, you'll need to walk down the entire thing once. Keep track of what the largest element is and update it if you see a larger one. If it is the same, add to the list.

```
largest_key = []
largest_value = 0
for key, value in lst.items():
    if value > largest_value:
        largest_value = value
        largest_key = [key]
    elif value == largest_value:
        largest_key.append(key)
```